How do I hide my virtual objects behind real-life objects using MRTK 3?
I have a unity app (2021.3 LTS) for hololens 2 where I use MRTK 3.
In my app I have an avatar (that I don’t control, I just see it move around) that moves around and a few buttons.
How do I make my avatar partially invisible in order for it to behave like a real-life object? For example, if it goes near a real-life table, I would like to not see its feet because they should be hidden behind the table.
In summary, how do I hide my avatar behind real-life objects using MRTK 3?
I already made some research but only found how to do it on MRTK 2.
I, also, went to MRTK XR Rig > Camera Offset > Main Camera and checked the "Occlusion Culling" checkbox but it had no effect.

Occlusion culling decides what will be skipped rendering because it is overlayed by another virtual object ... The phrase you would be looking for is rather "Masking"

To achieve what you are asking for, in MRTK3 you can use the ARMeshManager provided by Unity itself. J. van Schaik has a short and concise tutorial on how and what to do. You can also take a look at the MRTK3 Unity DevTemplate which contains a scene called SpatialMappingExample.unity.
In your case, for stuff to be occluded by real-life objects make sure to assign the occlusion prefab to the ARMeshManager component.
